# How can I wait a heavy function in method of React component with showing spinner?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, es6-promise

I want to show message "calculating..." during a heavy synchronous calculation in the React Component's method.
Here is my code.
But it doesn't works.
I want React to call render() both after first setState and second setState.
But React call it only after second setState.
How can I switch `this.state.calculating` properly?

```js
// note: this is not async function
function myHeavyFunc() {...}

class Foo extends React.Components {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {calculating: false}
    this.handleXX = this.handleXX.bind(this);
  }

  handleXX() {
    this.setState({calculating: true}, () => { // first setState
       new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const x = myHeavyFunc();
         resolve(x);
       }).then(x => {
         this.setState({calculating: false}); // second setState
       });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const y = this.state.calculating? <p>calculating...</p> : '';
    return (
      <div>
        {y}
        <button onClick={this.handleXX}>start calc</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you'll want to seperate the two. Run the first setState, on render if calculating === true run your function.

Comment: thank you for comment, but it's not work... It seems that Even though render() is called properly, applying render's result to dom is blokked by myHeavyFunc's execution. I notice this by trying to use componentDidUpdate(). It is called after render(), but apply to real dom is blokked...

Comment: in a function component this would be handled by a useEffect with a dependency array. componentDidUpdate() fires before paint, so it still blocks the dom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because js is single thread.

Only in such case, you can use setTimeout to give a time to update UI to show "calculating..." and then call myHeavyFunc.

More general solution is using startTrantision which is available in React 18.

Webworker may olso solve this.

Answer (score 0):

After finishing your calculation, you should set the "calculating" state variable back to "false" instead of "true":

```
handleXX() {
    this.setState({calculating: true}, () => { // first setState
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const x = myHeavyFunc();
            resolve(x);
        }).then(x => {
            this.setState({calculating: false}); // second setState
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry. it's typo. in my source code, it's `false`